# Encrypt credentials in App.config in Visual Studio 2019 using aspnet_regiis

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config, app-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

encrypt credentials in App.config in Visual Studio 2019

I need to Encrypt API credentials in my App.config in c# console application. I'm using .Net framework 4.7.2. I'm using aspnet_regiis.exe command-line tool provided by the .NET Framework.
These are the steps I'm taking:

Opened Visual Studio with Admin rights
Open the App.config file in the Visual Studio project.
In the App.Config file, I want to Encrypt "authorizationHeaderValue", which is located under    section under  section

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="authorizationHeaderValue" value="user:password"/>
  </appSettings>
.
.
.
</configuration>
```

Opened the Developer Command Prompt from Visual Studio.
Navigated to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319  (here is where aspnet_regiis.exe resides)
hence:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Then ran the command to encrypt. App.Config resides in this directory:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "authorizationHeaderValue" "C:\My Projects\ProjName"
```

I got the message:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pef "authorizationHeaderValue" "C:\My Projects\ProjName"
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section 'authorizationHeaderValue' was not found.
Failed!
```

After doing some research, I renamed my App.config to web.config, but still getting error

```
The configuration section 'authorizationHeaderValue' was not found.
Failed!
```

I have tried giving full access to folder and files under the project folder. Right click file, properties to sure file is not readonly.

Please suggest what is wrong.

Comment: _authorizationHeaderValue_ is not a section, is a key inside the section _appSettings_

Comment: you need to encrypt section .look in this article it might help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-encrypt-a-appsettings-key-in-webconfig